# Java: Display an Email body in Swing

Tags: java, swing, email

Is there a simple way to display an email body in a `JComponent`.
Just the body is enough, I will make labels and fields like: `from`, `to`, `subject`, ...

It would be very easy if I could do something like this:

```
Message m = ...; //From the java mail lib. (javax.mail.Message)
JEmailBodyComponent c = new JEmailBodyComponent(m);
frame.add(c);
```

Thanks

Comment: If it is just plain text, then isn't it just a text area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is some example code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/AClienttoSendSMTPMail.htm) to provide an email composition window in Swing. It should be trivial to populate the fields with the contents of an existing message.